# 2 (almost) identical programs don't get me the same results with the same input

Tags: python, variables, parameters, module

I've got a program that takes in input a **.txt file with coordinates (t, X, Y)**. The movement stored in this files is more or less *circular*, and this program is *counting the number of rotation* by searching the *local optima* of X+Y. 
The last part at the end is to plot the results.

You can find here 2 .txt : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxmtjR3C4bYBdnFZUzVwSVlPUlk/view?usp=sharing

*Here is the **first version** :*

The Interpolation function is a cubic interpolation that return False if it couldn't Interpolate, or (Frame_final, X_final, Y_final) if it managed to interpolate. 
The Filtrage function is a first-order lowpass-filter.

```
def Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, DT = 3, a = 0.1):
    """Fonction réalisant un filtrage passe-bas d'ordre 1 du signal."""
    # Initialisation
    X_temp, Y_temp = [], []
    X_filter, Y_filter = [], []
    i = 1
    X_temp.append(X[0])
    Y_temp.append(Y[0])

    # Filtrage par morceau
    while i < len(Frame)-1:

        while Frame[i] - Frame[i-1] == DT:
            Xnew = a * X[i-1] + (1 - a) * X_temp[len(X_temp)-1]
            Ynew = a * Y[i-1] + (1 - a) * Y_temp[len(Y_temp)-1]
            X_temp.append(Xnew)
            Y_temp.append(Ynew)
            if i < len(Frame)-1:
                i += 1
            else:
                break

        X_filter += X_temp
        Y_filter += Y_temp
        X_temp, Y_temp = [], []
        X_temp.append(X[i])
        Y_temp.append(Y[i])
        i += 1

    return (X_filter, Y_filter)



def Traitement_resultat(Chemin_dossier_res, Trace_Graph):
    """Fonction réalisant le traitement des résultats pour déterminer le nombre de tour
    effectué par la trajectoire circulaire.
    - Le paramètre Chemin_dossier_res est une str.
    - Le paramètre Trace_graph est un booléen
    """

    print ("Début du traitement des résultats")

    # Listage des fichiers résultats + ouverture du fichier de résultats finaux
    Fichiers_res = os.listdir(Chemin_dossier_res)
    res = open("Data_Results.txt", "w")
    res.write("{}               {}           {}\n".format("Souris", "Nombre de tours", "Distance parcourue"))

    # On boucle sur les fichiers
    for i in range(0, len(Fichiers_res)):
        # Affiche l'état du traitement
        print ("{} / {} : {}".format(str(i+1), str(len(Fichiers_res)), Fichiers_res[i]))

        # On ouvre le fichier résultat
        results = open("{}/{}".format(Chemin_dossier_res, Fichiers_res[i]), "r")

        # On récupère les datas dans 2 listes
        X, Y, Frame = [], [], []
        c = 0 
        try:
            for ligne in results:
                # Permet d'éliminer la première ligne d'en-tête
                if c >= 1:
                    row = ligne.split()
                    if row[0] == "None":
                        continue
                    else:
                        Frame.append(int(row[0]))
                        X.append(int(row[1]))
                        Y.append(int(row[2]))
                c += 1
            results.close()
        except:
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            results.close()
            continue

        if len(X) != len(Y):
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            continue

        # Inteprolation
        Data = Interpolation(Frame, X, Y)
        if not Data:
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            continue

        Frame = Data[0]
        X = Data[1]
        Y = Data[2]

        # Filtrage
        Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y)
        X = Data[0]
        Y = Data[1]

        Diff_len = len(Frame) - len(X)
        if Diff_len != 0:
            Frame = Frame[:len(Frame)-Diff_len]

        # Suppression des extremum
        if len(Frame) > 1000:
            for k in range(30):
                maxX_ID = X.index(max(X))
                del X[maxX_ID]
                del Y[maxX_ID]
                del Frame[maxX_ID]

                minX_ID = X.index(min(X))
                del X[minX_ID]
                del Y[minX_ID]
                del Frame[minX_ID]

                maxY_ID = Y.index(max(Y))
                del X[maxY_ID]
                del Y[maxY_ID]
                del Frame[maxY_ID]

                minY_ID = Y.index(min(Y))
                del X[minY_ID]
                del Y[minY_ID]
                del Frame[minY_ID]
        elif len(Frame) > 100:
            for k in range(3):
                maxX_ID = X.index(max(X))
                del X[maxX_ID]
                del Y[maxX_ID]
                del Frame[maxX_ID]

                minX_ID = X.index(min(X))
                del X[minX_ID]
                del Y[minX_ID]
                del Frame[minX_ID]

                maxY_ID = Y.index(max(Y))
                del X[maxY_ID]
                del Y[maxY_ID]
                del Frame[maxY_ID]

                minY_ID = Y.index(min(Y))
                del X[minY_ID]
                del Y[minY_ID]
                del Frame[minY_ID]
        else:
            print ("{} : Moins de 100 pts !!".format(Fichiers_res[i]))

        Sum = []
        # Conversion en minute et creation de la somme
        for k in range(len(Frame)):
            Frame[k] = Frame[k] / (30 * 60)
            Sum.append(X[k] + Y[k])

        if len(X) > 2:
            # Détermination de la distance parcourue
            Distance = 0
            for k in range(len(X)-1):
                Distance += sqrt((X[k+1] - X[k])**2 + (Y[k+1] - Y[k])**2)

            Segments = range(200, 1400, 200)                         
            Res = []

            for k in range(len(Segments)):
                if Segments[k] < len(Sum):
                    Sum_calc = []
                    length = len(Sum) // Segments[k]
                    last = len(Sum) % Segments[k]

                    for j in range(length):
                        Sum_calc.append(Sum[j:j + Segments[k]])

                    if last > Segments[k] //2:
                        Sum_calc.append(X[len(Sum) - last:])

                    else:
                        Sum_calc[len(Sum_calc) - 1] = Sum_calc[len(Sum_calc) - 1] + Sum[len(Sum) - last:]

                    # Initialisation of the counter
                    K = 0

                    for j in range(len(Sum_calc)):

                        Counter = 0
                        b = 0
                        Moyenne = np.mean(Sum_calc[j])
                        while b < len(Sum_calc[j]):
                            if Sum_calc[j][b] <= Moyenne + 10:
                                b += 1
                                continue
                            else:
                                Counter += 1
                                while Sum_calc[j][b] >= Moyenne + 10:
                                    b += 1
                                    try:
                                        Sum_calc[j][b]
                                    except:
                                        break
                        K += Counter

                    Res.append(K)

            if len(Res) > 4:
                Res_F = int(np.mean(sorted(Res)[1:len(Res)-1]))
            else:
                Res_F = int(np.mean(Res))

            # Ajout au fichier résultat des données
            res.write(Fichiers_res[i][0:len(Fichiers_res[i])-4] + " " * (25 - len(Fichiers_res[i])) + str(Res_F) 
            + " " * (26 - len(str(Res_F))) + str(int(Distance)) + "\n")

        if Trace_Graph:
            # Création des graphiques
            plt.figure(figsize = (15, 11), dpi = 600)

            # Ligne 2 / Colonne 1 / Position 1
            plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
            plt.plot(X, Y, color = "green", linewidth = 0.3, linestyle="-")
            plt.xlim(min(X) - 0.1 * np.mean(X), max(X) + 0.1 * np.mean(X))
            plt.ylim(min(Y) - 0.1 * np.mean(Y), max(Y) + 0.1 * np.mean(Y))
            plt.xlabel("pixel")
            plt.ylabel("pixel")
            plt.title("Trajectoire de la souris")

            # Ligne 2 / Colonne 1 / Position 2
            plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
            plt.plot(Frame, X, color = "blue", linewidth = 0.5, linestyle="-", label = "X")
            plt.plot(Frame, Y, color = "red", linewidth = 0.5, linestyle="-", label = "Y")
            plt.xlim(0, Frame[len(Frame)-1])
            plt.ylim(min(min(X),min(Y)) - 0.1 * min(min(X),min(Y)) , max(max(X),max(Y)) + 0.1 * max(max(X),max(Y)))
            plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
            plt.xlabel("Temps (minutes)")
            plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, int(Frame[len(Frame)-1]), int(Frame[len(Frame)-1]) + 1))
            plt.ylabel("Position")
            plt.title("Position X et Y de la souris en fonction du temps")

            plt.savefig("{}/{}.png".format("Graphiques", Fichiers_res[i][0:len(Fichiers_res[i])-4]), dpi = 600)
            plt.close()

    res.close()

    print ("Fin du traitement des résultats !")
    print ("---------------------------------------")
```

**The second programm is exactly the same, with only 3 minors change : some of the variable are placed in a different file**.

File Parameters.py :

```
# Parameters to adjust the analysis
# Low-pass filtering between 0 and 1
a = 0.1
# Thershold to count the maximum as a local maximum
Moy_Up = 10
# Segments cutting
Segments = range(200, 1400, 200)
```

Programm File :

```
from Parameters import *
def Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, DT = 3, a = 0.1):
    """Fonction réalisant un filtrage passe-bas d'ordre 1 du signal."""
    # Initialisation
    X_temp, Y_temp = [], []
    X_filter, Y_filter = [], []
    i = 1
    X_temp.append(X[0])
    Y_temp.append(Y[0])

    # Filtrage par morceau
    while i < len(Frame)-1:

        while Frame[i] - Frame[i-1] == DT:
            Xnew = a * X[i-1] + (1 - a) * X_temp[len(X_temp)-1]
            Ynew = a * Y[i-1] + (1 - a) * Y_temp[len(Y_temp)-1]
            X_temp.append(Xnew)
            Y_temp.append(Ynew)
            if i < len(Frame)-1:
                i += 1
            else:
                break

        X_filter += X_temp
        Y_filter += Y_temp
        X_temp, Y_temp = [], []
        X_temp.append(X[i])
        Y_temp.append(Y[i])
        i += 1

    return (X_filter, Y_filter)



def Traitement_resultat(Chemin_dossier_res, Trace_Graph):
    """Fonction réalisant le traitement des résultats pour déterminer le nombre de tour
    effectué par la trajectoire circulaire.
    - Le paramètre Chemin_dossier_res est une str.
    - Le paramètre Trace_graph est un booléen
    """

    print ("Début du traitement des résultats")

    # Listage des fichiers résultats + ouverture du fichier de résultats finaux
    Fichiers_res = os.listdir(Chemin_dossier_res)
    res = open("Data_Results.txt", "w")
    res.write("{}               {}           {}\n".format("Souris", "Nombre de tours", "Distance parcourue"))

    # On boucle sur les fichiers
    for i in range(0, len(Fichiers_res)):
        # Affiche l'état du traitement
        print ("{} / {} : {}".format(str(i+1), str(len(Fichiers_res)), Fichiers_res[i]))

        # On ouvre le fichier résultat
        results = open("{}/{}".format(Chemin_dossier_res, Fichiers_res[i]), "r")

        # On récupère les datas dans 2 listes
        X, Y, Frame = [], [], []
        c = 0 
        try:
            for ligne in results:
                # Permet d'éliminer la première ligne d'en-tête
                if c >= 1:
                    row = ligne.split()
                    if row[0] == "None":
                        continue
                    else:
                        Frame.append(int(row[0]))
                        X.append(int(row[1]))
                        Y.append(int(row[2]))
                c += 1
            results.close()
        except:
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            results.close()
            continue

        if len(X) != len(Y):
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            continue

        # Inteprolation
        Data = Interpolation(Frame, X, Y)
        if not Data:
            print ("Fichier {} eronné ! Il ne sera pas traité.".format(Fichiers_res[i]))
            continue

        Frame = Data[0]
        X = Data[1]
        Y = Data[2]

        # Filtrage
        Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, a)
        X = Data[0]
        Y = Data[1]

        Diff_len = len(Frame) - len(X)
        if Diff_len != 0:
            Frame = Frame[:len(Frame)-Diff_len]

        # Suppression des extremum
        if len(Frame) > 1000:
            for k in range(30):
                maxX_ID = X.index(max(X))
                del X[maxX_ID]
                del Y[maxX_ID]
                del Frame[maxX_ID]

                minX_ID = X.index(min(X))
                del X[minX_ID]
                del Y[minX_ID]
                del Frame[minX_ID]

                maxY_ID = Y.index(max(Y))
                del X[maxY_ID]
                del Y[maxY_ID]
                del Frame[maxY_ID]

                minY_ID = Y.index(min(Y))
                del X[minY_ID]
                del Y[minY_ID]
                del Frame[minY_ID]
        elif len(Frame) > 100:
            for k in range(3):
                maxX_ID = X.index(max(X))
                del X[maxX_ID]
                del Y[maxX_ID]
                del Frame[maxX_ID]

                minX_ID = X.index(min(X))
                del X[minX_ID]
                del Y[minX_ID]
                del Frame[minX_ID]

                maxY_ID = Y.index(max(Y))
                del X[maxY_ID]
                del Y[maxY_ID]
                del Frame[maxY_ID]

                minY_ID = Y.index(min(Y))
                del X[minY_ID]
                del Y[minY_ID]
                del Frame[minY_ID]
        else:
            print ("{} : Moins de 100 pts !!".format(Fichiers_res[i]))

        Sum = []
        # Conversion en minute et creation de la somme
        for k in range(len(Frame)):
            Frame[k] = Frame[k] / (30 * 60)
            Sum.append(X[k] + Y[k])

        if len(X) > 2:
            # Détermination de la distance parcourue
            Distance = 0
            for k in range(len(X)-1):
                Distance += sqrt((X[k+1] - X[k])**2 + (Y[k+1] - Y[k])**2)

            Res = []

            for k in range(len(Segments)):
                if Segments[k] < len(Sum):
                    Sum_calc = []
                    length = len(Sum) // Segments[k]
                    last = len(Sum) % Segments[k]

                    for j in range(length):
                        Sum_calc.append(Sum[j:j + Segments[k]])

                    if last > Segments[k] //2:
                        Sum_calc.append(X[len(Sum) - last:])

                    else:
                        Sum_calc[len(Sum_calc) - 1] = Sum_calc[len(Sum_calc) - 1] + Sum[len(Sum) - last:]

                    # Initialisation of the counter
                    K = 0

                    for j in range(len(Sum_calc)):

                        Counter = 0
                        b = 0
                        Moyenne = np.mean(Sum_calc[j])
                        while b < len(Sum_calc[j]):
                            if Sum_calc[j][b] <= Moyenne + Moy_Up:
                                b += 1
                                continue
                            else:
                                Counter += 1
                                while Sum_calc[j][b] >= Moyenne + Moy_Up:
                                    b += 1
                                    try:
                                        Sum_calc[j][b]
                                    except:
                                        break
                        K += Counter

                    Res.append(K)

            if len(Res) > 4:
                Res_F = int(np.mean(sorted(Res)[1:len(Res)-1]))
            else:
                Res_F = int(np.mean(Res))

            # Ajout au fichier résultat des données
            res.write(Fichiers_res[i][0:len(Fichiers_res[i])-4] + " " * (25 - len(Fichiers_res[i])) + str(Res_F) 
            + " " * (26 - len(str(Res_F))) + str(int(Distance)) + "\n")

        if Trace_Graph:
            # Création des graphiques
            plt.figure(figsize = (15, 11), dpi = 600)

            # Ligne 2 / Colonne 1 / Position 1
            plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
            plt.plot(X, Y, color = "green", linewidth = 0.3, linestyle="-")
            plt.xlim(min(X) - 0.1 * np.mean(X), max(X) + 0.1 * np.mean(X))
            plt.ylim(min(Y) - 0.1 * np.mean(Y), max(Y) + 0.1 * np.mean(Y))
            plt.xlabel("pixel")
            plt.ylabel("pixel")
            plt.title("Trajectoire de la souris")

            # Ligne 2 / Colonne 1 / Position 2
            plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
            plt.plot(Frame, X, color = "blue", linewidth = 0.5, linestyle="-", label = "X")
            plt.plot(Frame, Y, color = "red", linewidth = 0.5, linestyle="-", label = "Y")
            plt.xlim(0, Frame[len(Frame)-1])
            plt.ylim(min(min(X),min(Y)) - 0.1 * min(min(X),min(Y)) , max(max(X),max(Y)) + 0.1 * max(max(X),max(Y)))
            plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
            plt.xlabel("Temps (minutes)")
            plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, int(Frame[len(Frame)-1]), int(Frame[len(Frame)-1]) + 1))
            plt.ylabel("Position")
            plt.title("Position X et Y de la souris en fonction du temps")

            plt.savefig("{}/{}.png".format("Graphiques", Fichiers_res[i][0:len(Fichiers_res[i])-4]), dpi = 600)
            plt.close()

    res.close()

    print ("Fin du traitement des résultats !")
    print ("---------------------------------------")
```

I don't know why placing this parameters in a different file is changing my result. When I placed print (a), print (Moy_Up) and print (Segments) in the second program just before they are called, they have the right value (respectively, a, 10 and range(200, 1400, 200)).

But with the **first program** I get :

```
Souris               Nombre de tours           Distance parcourue
1                    48                        13062
2                    44                        12927
```

And with the **second one** :

```
Souris               Nombre de tours           Distance parcourue
1                    77                        40328
2                    76                        39235
```

Moreover, if in the second version I change back :

- Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, a) by Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y)
- Moy_Up by 10

and place back the Segments line, my results come back to those of the first version (quite normal).

Thanks for reading this long post, I tried to be explicit with my problem. I just can't understand why placing this variable in a separate file change my result even thou if I print them, they have the right value.

EDIT : I've used the compare module of Notepad, there is nothing else that differs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `Filtrage` as follows:

```
def Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, DT = 3, a = 0.1):
```

Note the fourth parameter is `DT`, but when you call it:

```
Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, a)
```

...you're passing `a` as the fourth parameter. You probably mean to do:

```
Data = Filtrage(Frame, X, Y, a=a)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I knew it was a dummy mistake, just couldn't find it ... Works fine now !